# Multiple Levels Of Inheritance Using Django Templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm creating a Django project, where I want to use multiple levels of inheritance in my templates. E.g I want to do something like this:

project_base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in app_base.html I extend this.

```
{% extends "project/project_base.html" %}
{% block title %}Generic Title{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <img src="/dir/sub_dir/image.jpg">
    {% block app_content %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Finally I have my actual template

```
{% extends app_base.html %}
{% block title %}Specific Title{% endblock %}
{% block app_content %}
    {% for obj in objects %}
        <a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">{{ obj.name }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The problem that I have is that when I go to load that page I see a single heading from an entirely unrelated template, and not my list of hyperlinks. What's the correct/best way to have multiple levels of inheritance for my template files?

Comment: What you have done looks correct in terms of template inheritance. Are you sure you have no typos? in your actual template {% extends 'app_base.html %} the template name has to be in quotes.

Comment: This all looks right. Maybe try putting single quotes around app_base.html in {% extends 'app_base.html' %}?